# Spring Amqp Hibernate vs Rabbit Transaction Manager

Tags: spring-transactions, spring-amqp

I have a spring-amqp consumer using a transactional SimpleMessageListenerContainer. The TransactionManager set on the container is a RabbitTransactionManager. My MessageListener calls a service method that has the @Transactional annotation on it. In spring I have a HibernateTransactionManager with the @Primary annotation on the bean declaration that I intend to be used for my repositories and services.

**My Question**

In the case described above, does the HibernateTransactionManager get used for the service method call that happens within my MessageListener?

**Why I'm asking**

I'm investigating a bug with our system where some data did not get persisted and I'm trying to rule out a faulty TransactionManager configuration.

**How I would like it to work**

I would prefer to have the message requeued if a database rollback occurs. Could I just remove the RabbitTransactionManager altogether and use the HibernateTransactionManager instead?

I'll be happy to provide my spring configuration if there is any confusion about what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, if you have fully blown `PlatformTransactionManager`, you should use it for the Spring AMQP `MessageListenerContainer` as well.

Since RabbitMQ doesn't support transactions in its nature like JMS, the `RabbitTransactionManager` isn't not requirement and must be replaced by the existing transactional resource support.

The Spring AMQP components are participating in the transaction synchronization properly.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#_using_the_rabbittransactionmanager

Comment: Great! Thanks for the clarification!